# Integral of associated Legendre polynomials over the unit interval

Tags: reference-request, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function, legendre-polynomials

I am looking for a closed-form expression for the integral of the associated Legendre polynomial $P_l^m$ over the unit interval ($l \ge m$ non-negative integers),
$$
I_l^m = \int_{0}^{1} P_l^m(x) \, dx \;.
$$
[There is an expression](http://functions.wolfram.com/05.07.21.0004.01) for $I_l^m$ in terms of Clausen's hypergeometric function $_3F_2$ (e.g. Gradshteyn & Ryzhik, 7.126.2),
$$
I_l^m = \frac{(-1)^m \, \pi \, 2^{-2m-1}}{\Gamma\bigl(\frac{m+1}{2}\bigr) \, \Gamma\bigl(\frac{m+3}{2}\bigr)} \, \frac{(l+m)!}{(l-m)!} \, {_3F_2}\bigl(-\tfrac{l-m}{2}, \tfrac{m+l+1}{2}, \tfrac{m+2}{2}; m+1, \tfrac{m+3}{2}; 1\bigr) \;.
\tag{$\star$}
$$
However, when $l+m$ is even, $P_l^m$ is an even function, and
$$
I_l^m = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} P_l^m(x) \, dx \;.
$$
This integral [has a well-known expression](http://functions.wolfram.com/05.07.21.0006.01) in terms of gamma functions, which yields the simple form
$$
I_l^m = \frac{(-1)^m \, 2^{m-2} \, m \, \Gamma\bigl(\frac{l}{2}\bigr) \, \Gamma\bigl(\frac{l+m+1}{2}\bigr)}{\Gamma\bigl(\frac{l+3}{2}\bigr) \, \bigl(\frac{l-m}{2}\bigr)!} \qquad \text{($l+m$ even)} \;.
\tag{$\dagger$}
$$
The even case $(\dagger)$ follows from the hypergeometric function in $(\star)$ more or less directly using [Saalschütz' theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Pfaff-Saalsch%C3%BCtz_Theorem).

Is there a similarly simple expression for $I_l^m$ when $l+m$ is odd? The [result on the Wolfram page](http://functions.wolfram.com/05.07.21.0005.01) seems incorrect, as it is merely $(\dagger)$ in a more complicated form, and I could not find it in any of the usual references. Looking at numerical results, I do not see a qualitative difference between the even and odd cases, so I still have some small hope for a positive answer.

Comment: `2^(-1 + m) Sqrt[\[Pi]]
  Gamma[1 - m/2] HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1 - m/2, 1/2 (-l - m), 
   1/2 (1 + l - m)}, {1 - m, (3 - m)/2}, 1]` formula works for l+m  for: odd and for: `l>m` and `m<2`.

Comment: Have you checked the Abramowitz and Stegun handbook of special functions formulas?

Comment: @Joako Yes, there you can find two special cases which can be reduced to $(\dagger)$.